# WPF combobox List Items background question

Tags: wpf, combobox

I am kind of still learning WPF and am working with the combo box control.  I am trying to setup the combo box so that it's background is transparent and when you click on it, the list items that show up are transparent.

After doing some reading online, I started by exporting the combobox control template and the list items template and started tinkering with that.   I now have the combobox itself setup as transparent and have figured out how to change the list items when the mouse is over them but still haven't figured out how to change the 'default' white background that the combobox uses to display the list items when nothing has been selected yet..

I am assuming that it's in the combobox list items template...   anyone know what I need to change there?   (if it helps, what I am going for is for the combo box & items to be transparent so that the grid background will show through and then i can use the list items mouse over to change the entry in the list items that the user is pointing over to a different background.. I have figured that part out, but still trying to figure out how to make them all 'transparent' to begin with..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

ok, after messing around with this and searching a bit, I finally did find it here

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}">
                <theme:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                    <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}">
```

I changed the `dropDownBorder`'s `Background` property to `Transparent` and that fixed it...